# Proving the existence of a bridge in a tree

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph, and let $e \in E(G)$. Prove that $e$ is a bridge if and only if every spanning tree of $G$ contains $e$.

Can someone help me with this please? Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty direct usage of the definition of a bridge, I think.

Comment: I am quite stuck right now, which is why I posted here. Any tips/hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $e$ is a bridge  in $G$ and $T$ a spanning tree on $G$ not containing $e$. Then, since $T$ is a tree, it must be connected, but since $T$ is a subgraph of $G\setminus\{e\}$, a disconnected graph, it must be disconnected. Therefore, any spanning tree contains every bridge.

Now suppose $e$ is not a bridge. Then $G\setminus\{e\}$ is still connected, and so has a spanning tree $T$. However, since $G\setminus\{e\}$ has the same vertices as $G$, $T$ is also a spanning tree of $G$ that does not contain $e$. Therefore, any edge in every spanning tree is a bridge.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. This actually makes a lot of sense for me. Thank you very much!